# Quarkus OpenTelemetry and Local Agent

Tags: quarkus, open-telemetry

Quarkus documentation explains how to connect Quarkus with OpenTelemetry Collector in collector setup, where the endpoint address must be set (`quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint`).

How to configure it to work in Kubernetes with Collector deployed as agent on local node (DaemonSet)?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess "agent on local node" means that collector is running as K8S DaemonSet. So connect to IP of the local node and the port which is exposed. You can use `downward API` to get that IP.

Comment: Is that collector deployed like a sidecar?

Comment: @BrunoBaptista No, as a DaemonSet.

Comment: I imagine the daemonSet is accessed with localhost from inside the service. Assuming the port of the OTLP GRPC collector is standard, it should be 4317.
This would be the default config for the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jan Garaj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868457/quarkus-opentelemetry-and-local-agent/75905351#comment133826382_75868457) mentioned in his comment, you can use the the Kubernetes `Downward API` in order to get the node IP of the node where the container is running.

As the `OTel Collector` is running as `Daemonset` you will have an instance of the collector in each node.

Configure your app definition file to contain something like this:

```yaml
  env:
    - name: NODE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Then, in your Quarkus app you can use the environment variable `NODE_IP`, as follows:

`quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://${NODE_IP}:4317`